# Strip signatures and replies from emails

Tags: ruby, email, parsing

I'm currently working on a system that allows users to reply to notification emails that are sent out (*sigh*).

I need to strip out the replies and signatures, so that I'm left with the actual content of the reply, without all the noise.

Does anyone have any suggestions about the best way to do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If your system is in-house and/or you have a limited number of reply formats, it's possible to do a pretty good job. Here are the filters we have set up for email responses to trac tickets:

Drop all text after and including:

1. Lines that equal `'-- \n'` (standard email sig delimiter)
2. Lines that equal `'--\n'` (people often forget the space in sig delimiter; and this is not that common outside sigs)
3. Lines that begin with `'-----Original Message-----'` (MS Outlook default)
4. Lines that begin with `'________________________________`' (32 underscores, Outlook again)
5. Lines that begin with `'On '` and end with `' wrote:\n'` (OS X Mail.app default)
6. Lines that begin with `'From: '` (failsafe four Outlook and some other reply formats)
7. Lines that begin with `'Sent from my iPhone'`
8. Lines that begin with `'Sent from my BlackBerry'`

Numbers 3 and 4 are 'begin with' instead of 'equals' because sometimes users will squash lines together on accident.

We try to be more liberal about stripping out replies, since it's much more of an annoyance (to us) have reply garbage than it is to correct missing text.

Anybody have other formats from the wild that they want to share?

Comment: gmail uses `<div class="gmail_extra">...</div>`, and yahoo: `<div class="yahoo_quoted">...</div>` for quoted part (including "On .. wrote:")

Comment: It may be also be necessary to assume there may be one or more space character before the line (and at the end of the line for the lines end with \n matches). Line 5 for example could be `\n\s*On .* wrote:\s*\n*`

Answer (score 10):

Check out the email_reply_parser gem - https://github.com/github/email_reply_parser .  It does a nice job handling this problem.

Comment: Last I checked that project was not very well maintained (6 months for pull requests to get comments, etc).  I suggest https://github.com/lawrencepit/email_reply_parser instead.

Comment: Python library for mail parsing: https://github.com/alfonsrv/mailparser-reply/

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe you can do this **reliably** (signatures used to begin with `'--'` but I don't see that anymore). Perhaps you're better off asking people to reply inbetween text headers and then simply strip the reply from this ? It's not elegant, but perhaps more reliable.

e.g.

```
REPLY BETWEEN HERE -->

AND HERE -->
```

so you'd simply look for the required headers above and take what's inbetween.

Comment: Or even just:

REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE ------------------------------------

Comment: Indeed. Whatever is the most usable and least ambiguous.

Comment: How do you add that to standard replies?

Answer (score 4):

If you want something powerful & robust, and don't mind reading academic publications, you might check out this:

- [Learning to Extract Signature and Reply Lines from Email](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.11.2718)

Here's the homepage for one of the authors, with more info & some downloads:

- [Vitor R. Carvalho - Software and Datasets - (Vitor Carvalho)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~vitor/codeAndData.html)

Answer (score 1):

An approach that can be used for signature only (in addition to detect __ or --) is to test if the first name and/or family name of the sender is on a *short* line (~ containing 3 to 4 words, max).

The sender name is on the raw email header, most of the time next to the email address, like in:

`From: John Doe <jdoe@provider.com>`

This would be based on the assumption that you rarely write your own name in a email, and if you do so, it is probably in a *long* sentence.

Of course there will be some false positive, but it may not be a big problem depending on what you do (we use it to fold quoted text and signature into a ... gmail-style button, so overdetection does not end up into losing any content, it is just misplaced).

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that these emails are in plain text, just strip lines that begins with ">" as replies, and "-- " line should delimit signature. But those assumptions might not work, as not all people over internet use software that complies to rules.

Comment: This is the problem. I don't believe you can automate this reliably.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted since it's technically the same as upvoted accepted answer only a bit less comprehensive. Certainly not a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really nice PHP library dedicated to the email parsing

http://williamdurand.fr/EmailReplyParser/

https://github.com/willdurand/EmailReplyParser

Answer (score 0):

I made one for golang: https://github.com/web-ridge/email-reply-parser it detects signatures like

```
Karen The Green
Graphic Designer
Office
Tel: +44423423423423
Fax: +44234234234234
karen@webby.com
Street 2, City, Zeeland, 4694EG, NL
www.thing.com

The content of this email is confidential and intended for the recipient specified in message only. It is strictly forbidden to share any part of this message with any third party, without a written consent of the sender. If you received this message by mistake, please reply to this message and follow with its deletion, so that we can ensure such a mistake does not occur in the future.
```

```
Met vriendelijke groeten,
Richard Lindhout
```

Answer (score -3):

The [recommended signature delimiter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3676#section-4.3) is "-- \n". If people follow this recommendation, stripping signatures should be easy.

Comment: I don't see people using that any more, more's the pity.

Comment: Big IF... Recommended is certainly not standard in this case.