# Get Signature from GMail Message Payload

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api

I am playing around with the GMail API and can now fetch the message body from a returned message resource.

Now I am interested in how I can strip off the signature from that body, e.g. when I only want to return the text of the mail someone wrote, but not the signature many people have automatically attached from google in every mail.

For example:

```
// The actual message
Dear Sir,

here is an E-Mail for you.
Cheers

// Signature
John Doe
CEO of SuperDuper Inc.
SuperDuperStreet 200
New York City
```

I have not found anything regarding this in the documentation. Is the signature delivered in its own field or unsplittable attached to the message itself?

Comment: The signature is a part of the message, and is not in a separate field, sadly. Are you trying to extract the signature from a `html` part? Then you can find the signature within the `<div class=3D"gmail_signature"></div>` element.

Comment: @Tholle Yes I need to strip off the signature, good idea with just removing the div with the signature class. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to also try adding some filters as suggested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2193937/6092067) and see if it will help you.